# Using a dataframe to create a database in sql

Tags: python, database, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

How do I insert data stored in a dataframe to a database in SQL. I've been told that i should use pandas.

Here is the question:

1. Get data from Quandl. Store this in a dataframe. (I've done this part)
2. Insert data into a sqlite database. Create a database in sqlite and insert the data into a table with an appropriate schema. This can be done with pandas so there is no need to go outside of your program to do this.

Only started python coding couple of days ago, so bit of a noob to this.

What I've got so far:

```
import quandl

df = quandl.get("ML/AATRI", start_date="2008-01-01")

import pandas as pd 

import sqlite3
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should post the code from what you've done so far to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to first convert the data to `.sql` and then import the file in database workbench you are using. Suppose you have dataframe `df`, then using `pandas`, convert to `sql`.

```
import pandas as pd
df.to_sql('filename.sql', engine)
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out!